# Using triggers attached to enemy to make enemy jump in a 2.5d platformer

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I've got an enemy in my 2.5d platformer, that I already got to follow the player around, now I want him to jump over small obstacles, and honestly, I have no idea how to. My enemy is a sphere with rigidbody and a box collider scaled 2x in X axis, effectively making it 2 times wider than the sphere. I want this box collider to be a trigger and for it to launch a AddForce.
Where do I put the code for the trigger - if I put it in void update() wouldn't it apply force until the sphere is above the obstacle? I only want it to apply the force once.
Also, what would the code for the trigger look like?
So far I only got figured out how to find the rigidbody by getcomponent and apply force to it, and I watched a video on triggers, but it didn't really help :/

Comment: You seem so confused about everything in Unity and this question does not describe a particular problem. You should take a minute and follow a simple [Space Shooter tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial) This will get you started with all the Rigidbody, Trigger and Collider stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) method like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.tag == "IMakeEnemyJumpBeforeAnObstacle")
    {
        // add force here
    }
}
```

Note: this code should be in your enemy script. Plus use `IMakeEnemyJumpBeforeAnObstacle` tag on the trigger object which will be placed right before the obstacle. And make sure both the enemy and the other object have property `IsTrigger` checked from inspector.

[Learn More](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders)

Hope this helps

Comment: Wait, do I need "Is Trigger" on every single obstacle in the game?

Comment: not on obstacle. You need a trigger-collider placed near your obstacle which will tell your enemy to jump.

Comment: I realised this, got a trigger collider on my obstacle scaled to 1.5 in X, works like a charm. Thank you very much kind sir :)